# could not start the sphinx search service on local computer?

Tags: windows-services, sphinx

i am getting this

> Windows could not start the SphinxSearch service on Local Computer.
>
> Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

i got installation instruction from this .

http://blog.robbsnet.com/2011/07/how-to-install-and-implement-sphinx.html

build process is complete but when i start the sphinx search service i got errors .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running searchd manually from Command Prompt. Maybe it will give you a useful error message.

Try also looking in searchd.log

Comment: finally i got the error.

the error is that sphinx.conf file not found at proper position.


this file should be in "C:\Sphinx\bin" directory ..



thanks to barryhunter..

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still having problems with the Windows service:

1. Make sure your configuration is correct for both database and paths and the needed folders & files are created.
2. Make sure that the service "command" matches the correct paths and files, to do so you have to:

Run administrative tools, click on local services, then find SphinxSearch. Click on its properties and read the line the service is trying to execute. If the configuration path doesn't match the service start command, it will fail to start.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this can also happen because your search data files are corrupt. Easy fix for that is to nuke the files and refill them.