# Not able to start Sphinx Search- error 1067

Tags: sphinx

I am trying to install the Sphinx Search Server. I followed the steps given here http://itsonrail.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/installing-sphinx-on%C2%A0windows/

I added `C:\Sphinx\bin` to environment path and Sphinx Search is listed in the Services panel. When I try to start it, this error occurs:

`Windows could not start SphinxSearch service on local computer`
`Error: 1067 The process terminated unexpectedly.`

Please help me solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

I trid this http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=2684 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error in my Windows 7 x64. The step below helped to solve my problem:

Create folders **data** and **log** in **C:\Sphinx**.
Then try to start sphinx with cmd:

```
C:\sphinx\bin>searchd
```

Comment: If you are running it first time, First run indexer --all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726285/could-not-start-the-sphinx-search-service-on-local-computer  

View this link 2nd answer 2nd comment. Actually bin dir also need the config file.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem and eventually moved the sphnix.conf to C:\Sphinx\bin\sphnix.conf from root and the services starts. Please try this. (Please make sure there are data\, log\ directories in the root with write permission)

Comment: Thanks @Banty. It help me to start the SphinxService

Answer (score 0):

It is looking like your configuration is not setup properly. Have you tried to run search daemon from sphinx directory path via command prompt?

```
C:\sphinx\bin> searchd
C:\sphinx\bin>indexer --rotate –all
```

Also please ensure the log via search.log or windows event log.

If it is not running after this than try to reinstall it again

I hope it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Error 1067 doesn't say much about the problem, except that the process terminated unexpectedly. Try looking some more informations in **searchd.log**.

I've got same error code when I tried to update Sphinx with newer version. 
In the log file, I've found

> FATAL: no valid indexes to serve

My problem was that I tried running new version of Sphinx using index files created with an older version. It was solved by deleting all old index files and creating new indexes.

Answer (score 0):

==>> close your cmd window and restart the sphinxsearch service...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error suddenly, when Shpinx was working fine yesterday. Turns out the query log file was hitting 4Gb in size. I deleted it, and service started with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the folders defined in the conf file actually exist. I was missing the LOG folder and that's why I was getting the error. Once I added the folder, the problem was solved.