# Sphinx Not Running as Windows Service

Tags: configuration, windows-services, sphinx

For the longest time, I have been able to run Sphinx as a Windows Service by running the following commands:

```
indexer.exe --all --config ../sphinx.conf
c:\Sphinx\bin\searchd.exe --install --config c:\Sphinx\sphinx.conf --servicename Sphinx
```

For whatever, this stopped working today.  Now, I am receiving the dreaded 1067 error.  A look at the even logs provides no real information.

The only way to run this application is from the console:

```
>searchd.exe -c ../sphinx.conf
```

Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: On occasion, I receive the following warning:  WARNING: max_matches=2147483647 out of bounds; using default 1000

Comment: Try the advices from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066084/not-able-to-start-sphinx-search-error-1067

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions to no avail.